# Is there any way to update state by find Item and replace on a nested state?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I am building an order functionality of my modules in the component state on react 
so the state object looks like that

```
 "activity": {
            "name": "rewwerwer",
            "description": "werwerwerwerwer",
            "modules": [
                {
                    "name": "Text",
                    "order": 1,
                    "module_id": 1612,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Text2",
                    "order" 2,
                    "module_id": 1592,
                }
            ]
        }



handleSortUp = (moduleid ,newOrder) => {
        const { modules } = this.state.activity;
        const module = modules.find(element => element.module_id === moduleid);//Thios returns the correct object 

         this.setState({ activity: { ...this.state.activity.modules.find(element => element.module_id === moduleid), order: newOrder } });
}
```

I tried this but it updates the order field and object 
 but also removes all other objects from modules array :<

I like just to replace only the order field on each module by module id
and leave rest data there

the required response from the state that i need when the handleSortUp(1612,14); is fired

```
        handleSortUp(1612,2);


        {
            "name": "rewwerwer",
            "description": "werwerwerwerwer",
            "modules": [
                {
                    "name": "Text",
                    "order": 2,
                    "module_id": 1612,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Text2",
                    "order": 1,
                    "module_id": 1592,

                }
            ]
        }
```

I can do this on a simple array the question is how to update the State on react
Also the one way to change the order is answered fine  but how also to change the field that had that order registered 
So when we fire Change Item 1 order to 2 the Item 2 needs to take the Order 1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure! This would be a great place to use the built-in .map method available for arrays. Consider the following example.

```
let array = [{order: 1, type: "food"}, {order: 2, type: "notfood"} ]

const newArray = array.map((item) => {
   //CHECK TO SEE IF THIS IS THE ITEM WE WANT TO UPDATE
    if(item.order == 1){
        return {
            ...item,
            newField: "newData"
        }
    } else {
        return item
    }
})
```

Output is:

```
[{order: 1, type: "food", newField: "newData"}
{order: 2, type: "notfood"}]
```

So yes you could totally update the module you're looking for without mutating the rest of your array. Then use your findings to update the component state using some good ol spread.

```
this.setState({
    activity: {
        ...this.state.activity,
        modules: newArray}
})
```

Comment: I dont see here how you will update state i can do it with many ways in an array but i the question is how to update the nested state in react p[ropably with operator ...

Comment: @Agamem Sorry I left out the state-updating part. I just edited my answer with how I would update the nested state with the new data. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Agamem. You're very welcome. Welcome to stackoveflow!

Comment: Ok this worked nicely but i like also to replace the order on the replaced id > what i mean is now i change the order field of item but on my array there is an item with this order how can i do that ? in your example [{order: 1, type: "food", newField: "newData"}
{order: 2, type: "notfood"}] so if i change the order 2 to order 1 i like the item with order 2 to take value 1 (sorting)

Comment: @Agamem, can you elaborate on this? Do you mean, you want the chosen order to change its id? This seems like a different question altogether.

Comment: I have update the example what the output should be  when i cahnge the Item 1 from Order 1  to 2 i want also the item that had the Order2 to become 1

Answer (score 0):

Of course they get all eliminated. Pay attention to what you wrote here:

```
this.setState({ activity: { ...this.state.activity.modules.find(element => element.module_id === moduleid), order: newOrder } });
```

What are you doing with that find? Let's see what Array.prototype.find() returns: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
It returns an index, why would you insert an index into the state?

The answer partially came from yourfavoritedev.
As he said you can use the built-in Array.prototype.map() and do it like this:

```
handleSortUp = (moduleid ,newOrder) => {
  const { modules } = this.state.activity;
  const newModules = modules.map(module => module.module_id === moduleid ? { ...module, order: newOrder } : module)
  this.setState({ activity: { ...this.state.activity, modules: newModules } });
}
```

This should work, let me know but I strongly advice to ask me or search on the web if you don't understand what is happening there (syntactically or semantically speaking).

Comment: Worked fine also this i know also got the point of find thank you very much

Comment: Thank you, if you have any other question ask me, or resolve the question accepting the right answer :)
Happy hacking!